# How to specify connection string for Entity Framework in WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I normally work with ASP.NET MVC web projects so the connection string always goes into the `web.config` file.

Where do I put it in my WPF project?

Comment: When you create windows applications, you can add connectionstrings in App.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in your app.config under the `configSections` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <configSections>    
     ...
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyModel" connectionString="MyConnectionString" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
```

If you don't have an app.config file you can create one manually.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to create an App.config file in your project by hand. Then you can fill it up as usual.